# How to register an Eureka Client silently?

Tags: spring-cloud

**Background**

We have almost a hundred Eureka clients (spring cloud apps) being registered to an Eureka discovery server. One client can depend as many as more than 10 other clients. Traditionally, we have to run all the dependencies (along with discovery and config server) on local dev environment when developing against one client. Sometimes, to avoid bring up so many projects, I just connect the single client I am working on to our integration test environment which has all clients running. This way, it is very convenient for myself, but having a critical issue: my local client can be discovered by other clients, meaning someone else's testing might be effected by my instance. I know there are ways to mock or proxy the client dependencies. But they are not always good for every scenario, also the setup takes additional time.

**Question**

Is there a practically quick and easy way to register a client without being discovered by other clients. Besides, I can not issue

```
PUT /eureka/v2/apps/appID/instanceID/status?value=OUT_OF_SERVICE
```

or other discovery server side command. I can only configure my local project.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve that is adding the below property only in your local profile.

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
```

If so, your application still can look up other instances from Eureka, but your application will not register itself into Eureka.